# Dirichlet Problem: symmetry of the solution with respect to the $x_1$ variable

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, laplacian, elliptic-equations

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that for every $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\Omega$, the point $(-x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is also in $\Omega$. Let $u\in C^2(\Omega)\cap C^0(\overline{\Omega})$ be a solution of the Dirichlet problem
$$
\begin{cases}
\Delta u = 0\hspace{0.3cm}\text{in}\hspace{0.3cm}\Omega\\
u = \phi\hspace{0.3cm}\text{on}\hspace{0.3cm}\partial\Omega
\end{cases}
$$
where $\phi\in C^0(\partial\Omega)$ verifies $\phi(-x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\phi(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$. Prove that
$$
u(-x_1,\ldots,x_n)=u(x_1,\ldots,x_n).
$$

Comment: Hint: Use uniqueness of the solution...

Comment: may be using green function $u=\int G\phi$ ...should the integral preserve the symmetry?

Comment: Do you mean the representation formula $u(x_0)=\int_{\partial\Omega}\phi(x)\frac{\partial G(x,x_0)}{\partial\nu}ds$, $x_0\in\Omega$ ?